# Large Dataset for a directed, labeled graph

Tags: graph

i am looking for a big dataset for a labeled graph.

The graph should have the following characteristics:

- labeled Nodes and Edges (In the best case, the graph contains several nodes/edges with the same label - no unique labels)
- directed (hopefully - but may not necessarily needed)

I have already searched but found nothing matching with my problem. Only something like https://snap.stanford.edu/data/, but non of the graphs satisfy my desire.

Comment: Why not generating them yourself?

Comment: I want to see how many (special) pattern in the graph exists. If i create a graph with random edges and labels, it would not really works.

Comment: There is not one graph-generator, there are tons of generators creating different graphs (networkx has >50 generators). But i'm puzzled by your approach. You are looking for patterns in graphs, but don't have any special graph in mind? What's wrong with the graphs from your link?

Comment: the most graphs in the link don't have labels for nodes and edges. And another point why i don't want to create an own random graph is because i need a practical use (for an academic study).

Comment: A lot / most academic papers use random-graphs (with a reason; again: these generators are crafted to mimic practical graphs, e.g. social-networks) but well... i can't offer more help, because i don't like it to link to any graphs without knowing what you will do. This does not feel academic.